# Word meaning "narrow minded person" that ends in "an" if such exists

Tags: antonyms, rhymes

I'm looking for a word which is opposite or similar to *Cosmopolitan* and also ends in "an".

I'm trying to title something opposite or related to Cosmopolitan the magazine which sounds similar. So the goal is either an antonym or something that rhymes and is masculine.

I am specifically looking for an antonym for the word, but barring that such does not exist that ends in "an" at least in sound, I'll go with any word that rhymes that is in some way a masculine word.

From dictionary.com
cos·mo·pol·i·tan/ˌkɒzməˈpɒlɪtn/ Show Spelled [koz-muh-pol-i-tn] Show IPA 
adjective 
1. free from local, provincial, or national ideas, prejudices, or attachments; at home all over the world. 
2. of or characteristic of a cosmopolite. 
3. belonging to all the world; not limited to just one part of the world. 
4. Botany, Zoology . widely distributed over the globe. 
noun 
5. a person who is free from local, provincial, or national bias or attachment; citizen of the world; cosmopolite. 
6. a cocktail made with vodka, cranberry juice, an orange-flavored liqueur, and lime juice.

Antonyms:  narrow, narrow-minded, specific

So are there any words that mean "narrow minded person" that end in "an"?

Comment: it doesn't end -an but Provincial is roughly an antonym.

Comment: I downvoted this, because you're asking for an antonym, but it's not entirely clear if you're looking for the antonym of the word _cosmopolitan_ (which means "someone who has learned a lot about other cultures") or the magazine (which would be much more akin to asking for an antonym of "women in their 20s learning about relationships, sex, health, celebrities, and fashion"). Either way, it's hard to pin down what an "opposite" would be. One other note: please don't answer me in a comment, answer for everyone by improving your question with additional clarifications.

Comment: @J.R. Done as requested

Comment: English words that end in *-politan* seem to be limited to the following: *Constantinopolitan, cosmopolitan, extra-metropolitan, intrametropolitan,
megalopolitan, metropolitan, microcosmopolitan, Neapolitan, necropolitan,
non-metropolitan, pentapolitan, tetrapolitan, topopolitan, Tripolitan,
tropicopolitan.*

Comment: If you are going for the opposite of "cosmopolitan and urbane" 
you can use "suburban" or "parochial" (from Google dictionary: Having a limited or narrow outlook or scope) - though parochial doesn't end with an "an"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a real world or not, but I found this on [one website](http://www.kokogiak.com/logolepsy/ow_p.html#paltripolitan):

> **paltripolitan**
>   *n*. - an insular city dweller

*[Insular](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insular)* seems reasonably contrarian to *[cosmopolitan](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cosmopolitan)*, and it fits the word format you want.

The word is also listed in the [Phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info/p.html) (as a "term of scorn"), but I'm not so sure that adds much credibility to the validity of a word.

The OED lists it as a word, but defines it as "A metropolitan bishop" with this etymology:

> Blend of PALTRY *adj*. + METROPOLITAN *n*.

The OED also lists it as `derogatory`, `Obs.` and `rare`.

I'm assuming you want this for some sort of parody; this word might work for that, although I don't expect anyone would know what it means without a little extra guidance provided.

Comment: I'm liking altripolitan, good find, and though dictionaries don't seem to know it, I see it used in a few books pre 1900.

Comment: Because you never said it had to be a word recognizable by the layman, this word meets all your stated requirements. ;^) (I do realize its rarity is a liability, though.)

Comment: Um, you don't mean *paltripolitan*? It seems you forgot the *p-*.

Comment: @Cerberus: I'm surprised no one edited that yet; yes, thank you.

Comment: @J.R.: Heh, it seemed *so* obvious that I thought there *must* be a good reason...

Answer (score 2):

M-W states that *cosmopolitan* derives from the French *[cosmopolite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cosmopolite) + -ain*, and lists these antonyms for *cosmopolite*:

> bumpkin, hick, provincial, rustic, yokel

Of these, perhaps *rustic* would combine most mellifluously with *-an*; so call your faux magazine *Rustican*.

Comment: I had thought of suggesting _Local Yokel_.

Comment: @J.R. Yeah, I can imagine the possible cover designs for that...

Answer (score 0):

I would just use *not cosmopolitan*.

Comment: Or "uncosmopolitan" or "anti-cosmopolitan". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something else to consider is **Arcadian**, which is a noun [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Arcadian) one who leads or prefers a simple life. Also an adjective, with these [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/arcadian): bucolic, countrified, country, idyllic, innocent, peaceful, provincial, rural, rustic, simple.

Also, **solitudinarian**, which ends with "an" (but is not especially harmonious juxtaposed with "cosmopolitan") [means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/solitudinarian) one leading a solitary or secluded life. This type of person would never be accused of being a worldly bon vivant or cosmopolitan.

---

**Backwoodsman** is US informal for an uncouth or rustic person. A bumpkin, hick, yokel.

And it ends with "an".

There is also "frontiersman" and "mountain man" (two words, though).

Update

You might consider that a backwoodsman would have an insular lifestyle and have a provincial parochial point of view, unlike a cosmopolitan.

As an interesting aside, [I found this](http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2010/feb/15/michael-gove-backwoodsmen-rumbling-grumbling). It seems to describe someone who is uncosmopolitan and narrow minded. From the article: "Backwoodsmen" is a pejorative description of backbench Tory peers dating from the time when their party had a majority in the Lords and they were so disengaged from the democratic process they would only attend parliament to defeat legislation opposed by their party.

Comment: Jinx on "parochial", Jim! I didn't see your answer when I used that in a comment! :-)

Comment: And I thought everyone not only carefully reads every word I write, but also the words that are between the lines.

Comment: Don't we all - ~alas!~